# Understand Wagtail SourceCode

Tags: wagtail

when reviewing the Wagtail sourcecode:

```
class Page(AbstractPage, index.Indexed, ClusterableModel, metaclass=PageBase):
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('title'),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_("The page title as you'd like it to be seen by the public")
    )

    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name=_('slug'),
        allow_unicode=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_("The name of the page as it will appear in URLs")
    )
```

I do not understand `_('title')` & `_('slug')`, can anyone share some hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"_(...)"` function will be imported from the top of the file as:

`from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`

From the Django docs:

> These functions store a lazy reference to the string – not the actual
> translation. The translation itself will be done when the string is
> used in a string context, such as in template rendering.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation